# Should views search specific caching skip preprocess?

Tags: 7, views, caching, search

**Problem**

I have a view powered by the Search API, which uses the views inbuilt caching - "Search Specific" in order to provide better performance.

However I also run a number of theming alterations in:

`theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted`

However this code appears to be skipped when the views caching kicks in. Is this by design or an I encountering a bug? If it's not, how have people gotten around this sort of thing before?

**Re-creation**

- Clear all caches Load page - *Code runs correctly*
- Refresh the page a number of times usually between 2 & 5
- Refresh the page - *Code is skipped*

I've been testing if the code is skipped by including:

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  ...
  watchdog('test', 'This chunk of code has just run');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misusing `theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted`.

I'm running views caching, search specific (I think this may also apply to time specific) in order to cache the results of the view.

This caches the HTML of the view and means that the entire view creation, render and theming steps are skipped. When the view calls the search the correct HTML is returned.

However they do have to be run originally to build the cache. (For some reason it kicks in after a random number of refreshes? Perhaps there's simply a delay on creating the cache.)

I was using `watchdog` to log when the code runs and so obviously this only runs until the cache is created. This won't be an issue if everything you're doing in 
`theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted` alters the HTML because that will be cached the first time it happens. However I was using it to add text to header based on the results of the view, which obviously didn't work.

This was possibly muddled by the fact that I run Varnish & Authcache on my live environment so I think this would cache the initial version (before the search cache is built) and thus stop me from re-creating the bug on my live version.

Make sure you're aware of all your caches and how they run!